# Cocos2D application with menu and sprites crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone

I always used ARC but my cocos2d template doesn't use ARC, to I have to use the manual ref counting and that's probably why I crash.
The goal is to make a menu with two labels, if I click to a label, I show an image with a sprite.If I click on the image, I can go back to the menu and choose again.
This is the CCLayer class:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        CCMenuItemLabel* item1, *item2;
        CCLabelTTF* label1= [CCLabelTTF labelWithString: @"Shark Icon" fontName: @"Arial" fontSize: 30], *label2;
        label2= [CCLabelTTF labelWithString: @"Cocos2D Icon" fontName: @"Arial" fontSize: 30];
        label1.color=  ccRED;
        label2.color= ccRED;
        [label1 retain];
        [label2 retain];
        item1=[CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel: label1 block:^(id sender)
        {
            NSLog(@"Clicked shark icon");
            [self removeChild: menu cleanup: NO];
            shark=[CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"shark.jpeg"];
            [shark setPosition: CGPointMake(150, 200)];
            [self addChild: shark];
            [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate: self priority: 0 swallowsTouches: YES];
        }];
        item2= [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel: label2 block:^(id sender)
        {
            NSLog(@"Clicked cocos2d icon");
            [self removeChild: menu cleanup: NO];
            icon=[CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"icon.png"];
            [icon setPosition: CGPointMake(150, 200)];
            [self addChild: icon];
            [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate: self priority: 0 swallowsTouches: YES];
        }];
        [item1 retain];
        [item2 retain];
        menu=[CCMenu menuWithItems: item1,item2, nil];
        [menu alignItemsVertically];
        [self addChild: menu];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate: self];
    [self removeChild: shark cleanup: NO];
    [self addChild: menu];
    return YES;
}
```

**What happens:** I click on "Shark Icon" (or "Cocos2D Icon"), then the shark image appears,if I click on it I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address= 0x70Baafc8)
```

I tried to print all addresses (menu, item1,etc...), and no one of the items has this address.Sometimes I even get an invalid address like 0x00000008 .

**EDIT**

I would solve the problem by just retaining menu, but I haven't understood why: menu is already retained:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite* shark;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite* icon;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCMenu* menu;
```

If I enable zombies I get this:

```
*** -[CCMenu tag]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7c71a10
```

So menu is a zombie but shouldn't the retain property make it be retained?
The strange thing is that I don't need to retain shark and icon, just menu.

Comment: set a brakepoint on ccTouchBegan so you know on which line your code crash

Comment: When I add the menu as child crashes, I would solve this by just retaining menu, **but I haven't understood why**.In the properties menu is nonatomic, retain, it should be already retained.

Comment: yes but only if you use the property! you use only the pointer. so make self.menu =

Comment: Understood.But why don't I need to retain also shark and icon?

Comment: any children don't need retain or alloc. It will auto gc after removefromparent.

Comment: If you're having so much issues with retain counting, why not switch over to ARC? http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enable-arc-cocos2d-project-video-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems: item1,item2, nil];
```

menu was never retained. if its a retain property use self.menu

you create a new shark every time but want to reuse your menu!

Comment: any parent retains it's children. so the menu will be retained because of [self addChild: menu]; line

Comment: cannot understand what do you mean

Comment: you are right that parent retains its children. but when you do removeChild:, menu will be released! and he whants to keep the menu object. (please be careful with your downvotes)

Comment: oh, sry. didn't notice that he removes menu on every btn click. it is strange a bit for me.